# Objects are not valid as a React child. Unable to extract month and year from picker

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I need user to select a month and year for credit card expiry and then show it in a text but getting below error

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_isAMomentObject, _i, _f, _isUTC, _pf, _locale, _d, _isValid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Below is my code

```js
const PaymentScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date("2011-11-11"));
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const showPicker = useCallback((value) => setShow(value), []);

  const onValueChange = useCallback(
    (event, newDate) => {
      const selectedDate = newDate || date;

      showPicker(false);
      setDate(selectedDate);
    },
    [date, showPicker]
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Month Year Picker Example</Text>
      <Text>{moment(date, "MM-YYYY")}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showPicker(true)}>
        <Text>OPEN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {show && (
        <MonthPicker
          onChange={onValueChange}
          value={date}
          minimumDate={new Date()}
          maximumDate={new Date(2025, 5)}
          locale="ko"
        />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default PaymentScreen;
```

Please guide how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```js
<Text>{moment(date).format("MM-YYYY")}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced the same issue. However, when I did `moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY")` then it started working... I guess while printing moment() in react it gives error hence its important to format it and then print it